# apply a CNN .h5 format model on the new data set

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have trained the model and save this model to a file [ cats_and_dogs_small_1.h5 ]. How can I apply this model to a separate test data (Own created picture from my mobile phone)?

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: If you're using keras this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469281/how-to-predict-input-image-using-trained-model-in-keras

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info. e.g Which framework are you using? Also, what do you mean by "apply" ? Do you wish to evaluate a new image using the trained model?